# React-Native packager stuck on `Requesting bundle`

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run a boilerplate react-native app and the packager seems to stall out right at the beginning when the javascript bundle is requested. Eventually the iOS simulator gives up and throws `Could not connect to development server.`

Here is the terminal output:

```
[01/17/2017, 10:48:00] <START> Initializing Packager
[01/17/2017, 10:48:00]         HMR Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

[01/17/2017, 10:48:47] <START> Requesting bundle
                               bundle_url: /index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false
```

I haven't been in react-native for a few months but I used to be able to specify whether the app should load from a bundle or just load the js directly. I would load directly when the xCode project was in `debug` mode or from a bundle when in `release` mode.

Again this is just straight boilderplate - no external packages or anything. Just using `react-native init TestProj` and then `cd TestProj/ && react-native run-ios`

I'm using the last version of react-native `0.40.0` and the expected react dependency of `react@~15.4.0-rc.4`.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: if you haven't already, run react-native start from a separate terminal in your project directory. This starts the packaging server.

Comment: @jpriebe the packager is running - that's the output I listed in my question. It just seems to be stalled when requesting the bundle url `/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false`. I'm not sure why it's requesting a bundle in the first place. The bundle file does not exist.

Comment: can you try running
`curl "http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios" -o "ios/app/src/main/assets/index.ios.bundle"`

Comment: sometimes the bundler hangs for me on a spotty network, shouldn't matter since you're running an emulator on the same machine but this might force it to update your bundle

Comment: I'm giving that a try now. It seems like I shouldn't need a bundle just to start simulating the app and making changes. Is there a way to run the simulator without a js bundle?

Comment: AFAIK you only need the actual server running to do hot reloading, but you always need a bundle to actually package and run the app

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue was but it was fixed after I restarted my computer. I also had issues getting the code to refresh once the app was loaded. That was fixed by uninstalling nodemon globally.